# Why should methods return a new instance, rather than modify the instance itself?

Tags: c++, oop

Suppose I have a `Vector3` class, that contains a `normalize()` method. Should that method return a new `Vector3`, or modify the `Vector3` instance it is called on (therefore returning a reference to itself (`Vector3&`)?) What are some instances where one would be preferred over the other? What about performance?

Comment: Could you add some code examples? I can't figure out what you are talking about exactly, but I believe you might be interested in reading [this](http://www.javapractices.com/topic/TopicAction.do?Id=29)

Comment: Competing goals: Correctness vs Performance (sometimes). If you use immutable types, you have it easier to write correct (parallel) programs. If you use mutable types, you sometimes have a certain performance benefit which might well be lost once you try to go parallel. Then there is the 80/20 rules. 80% of the code need not be optimized. So why use mutable types by default? First go immutable, then see if it has enough performance, then optimize, if not.

Comment: @BitTickler answer, not comment...

Comment: @BitTickler Only 80%? My very conservative estimate is about 95% don't need to be optimized, if you count by lines of code :-)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The answer depends on the design of your class.

For mutable classes `rotate` should rotate the vector itself. This is viewed as somewhat more efficient, and in case of large objects it lets you avoid copying large volumes of data when vectors have many items in them.

Immutable classes, on the other hand, must return only new objects, because they cannot be mutated themselves. This adds some overhead, but it has a lot of pluses, especially when objects must be used concurrently.

A common naming convention is to use a verb for mutating operations, as in

```
myVector.rotate(angle);
myVector.scale(factor);
```

while operations that return new objects should be named with [*past participles*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Participle), as in

```
auto newVector = myVector.rotated(angle).scaled(factor);
```

Answer (score 2):

Competing goals: Correctness vs Performance (sometimes).

If you use immutable types, you have it easier to write correct (parallel) programs. If you use mutable types, you sometimes have a certain performance benefit which might well be lost once you try to go parallel. Then there is the 80/20 rules. 80% of the code need not be optimized. So why use mutable types by default?

First go immutable, then see if it has enough performance, then optimize, if not.

Answer (score 0):

```
 Vector3 rotate(const Angle& angle)
```

is probably fine, but well depends on `Vector3` is implemented correctly. Especially regarding `std::move()` behavior.

Answer (score 0):

Side effects. If I pass an object that I retrieved from a map, for example, and you do something to the object I pass, you have changed the thing that is inside my map, and the next time I ask for it I get something that does not look the same as I got last time. Keeping objects immutable prevents accidents like this, especially when multiple devs are working on the same app.